# Linking different pages in Html with an animation

Tags: html

I am making a simple website that contains many photos. I have an index.html and I want to make a navigation bar. In the navigation bar I want to have contact, about etc. Is there any way I can link my index.html to lets say my contact.html. I know the standard way of linking them together ( with an a tag ) but I just wanted to know if there is a way to animate the effect of getting from one page to another. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Google "CSS". Your question shows no research effort, and it lacks details (what type of animation?)

Comment: You are looking for solutions with JavaScript. Especially Ajax and any variants/frameworks which animate the process of adding the returned data to your page. But your question is far too general to give more precise information.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way: use links which I would suggest because it is important that each page on your website has a focused purpose. Therefore, use a link and move the page. However, given the fact that it takes time for a page to load, animation is impractical because of the disjoin nature.

To include animation: you have to basically:

1. include the pages with php and then use css to make them appear/disappear onClick
2. use jquery to load in the pages asynchronously after an event (ie. Click).

Note however, the second method is quite complex and you really have to understand css and divs for the animation to work.

The actual animations are written in jquery or other languages that allow dynamic changes on the site.

Hope it helps.